# Mongoid::Tree ordering

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have following Category model:

```
class Category
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Tree

    field :title, type: String
    validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 2}
end
```

I have stored following test data:

```
Root 1
    Leaf 1
        Subleaf 1
    Leaf 2
Root 2
    Leaf 3
```

Now when i calling Category.all it returns:

```
Root 1
Leaf 2
Leaf 1
Root 2
Subleaf 1
Leaf 3
```

but i need following ordering:

```
Root 1
Leaf 1
Subleaf 1
Leaf 2
Root 2
Leaf 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mongoid::Tree` does not order trees by default. Instead it includes a module for ordering. Simply include it in your class:

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Tree
  include Mongoid::Tree::Ordering

  field :title, type: String
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 2}
end
```

That should already solve your problem. If not, take a look at the `Mongoid::Tree::Traversal` module that also comes with `Mongoid::Tree`. This will give you a `Category#traverse` method which lets you choose between breath first or depth first (that's what you want, I'd guess) traversal.

For more documentation on Ordering and Traversal see http://benediktdeicke.com/mongoid-tree/#Ordering and http://benediktdeicke.com/mongoid-tree/#Traversal